# C# Regex remove $select clause

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove the $select part of a OData query and the possible strings are the following

```
$select=FirstName,LastName
$select=FirstName,LastName&$filter=FirstName eq 'John'
$filter=FirstName eq 'John'&$select
```

So the rules I came out are the following:

- Remove everything that start with $select until the end if no & characters
- Remove everything that start with $select until the next &
  Is there a way to write one regex to test both scenarios and clean my OData URL?

Right now I have the following tests:

```
var query = "$select=FirstName";
var query = "$select=FirstName&$filter=FirstName eq 'John'";
var query = "$filter=FirstName eq 'John'&$select=FirstName";
var query = "$filter=FirstName eq 'John'";
```

I need also to remove the & if $select is the first clause or the preceding & if $select is the last clause

Comment: funny that you still have to ask 1k rep users what they have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
^\$select[^&]*
```

Should do it

Explanation:

```
^          start of string (remove this if that's not actually a requirement)
\$select   match the literal string "$select" 
           (note that $ is escaped because $ is end of string)
[^&]*      match anything that ISN'T an &, greedy
```

Comment: I have a test fitness with 10 different situations, I will try this now and see how it works. [^&] stands for Optional?

Comment: "$select=FirstName" is working
"$select=FirstName&$filter=FirstName eq 'John'" is working
"$filter=FirstName eq 'John'&$select=FirstName" is not

How can I remove the "begin with"?

Comment: Remove the beginning of string `^` anchor